# Which GeoTrust certificate supl.google.com uses?

Tags: gps, ssl-certificate

Trying everything to improve GPS on Android, so I decided to convert `*.pem` certificate to `SuplRootCert`.

But I can't understand: which certificate `supl.google.com:7252` uses:
`GeoTrust Global CA` or `GeoTrust Global CA 2`?

And by the way, which SUPL version `supl.google.com` supports?